# My custom webfont is not displaying properly in iOS 16

Tags: font-face, webfonts, hebrew, ios16, opentype

I have a [website](https://test.alhatorah.com/MikraotGedolot/Dual/Rashi/Shemot/2.1) with Hebrew text which contains [niqqud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niqqud) and [cantillation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_cantillation) (both are sets of diacritic marks).

In order to ensure the proper display of these marks, I embedded a font on my site. Using FontForge, I modified the original font, adding two stylistic sets (`ss01` and `ss02`).

The original font displays correctly; however, on Apple devices (Safari on Mac and iOS), the new font is causing problems.

When I embed the new version of the font, the text suddenly displays as if none of the font features are enabled (despite the fact that `mark`, `ccmp`, and `mkmk` should be enabled by default, and that I enabled them explicitly in the CSS).

On Windows, in all browsers, this font is displaying appropriately.

An example of the incorrect behavior:

[image]

I tried changing font formats from woff to ttf, but nothing changed. At the moment, I placed a CSS Hack embedding the old version instead of the new version in all Safari browsers, but I would really like to be able to use my new Stylistic Sets in Safari as well.

A test site without the CSS Hack can be found [here](https://test.alhatorah.com/MikraotGedolot/Dual/Rashi/Shemot/2.1); the text with the issues is in the right side of the page.

Comment: You _definitely_ want to ask this over on https://typedrawers.com instead of Stackoverflow.